# Robocopy not logging folders

Tags: robocopy

Robocopy is randomly not logging folders in the log.  I'm using exactly the same switches but copying the same or different folders.  See picture at bottom..
I used:
robocopy "F:\folderSample2"" d:\SAMPLE2COPED /MIR  /R:0 /MT:32 /NP /B /log:g:\NOverbose3.LOG

[image: with folders]

[image: w/o folders]

Comment: You are not using the same switches, see the options line in both Robocopy outputs (although I didn't check if the difference is significant). Sre you sure the destination directory is empty (no empty folders etc.) if so, how did you verify this?